# Where in the world is this astronomical convergence?

Tags: knowledge, geography, outer-space

At this location on planet Earth, on April 8, 2024, you can observe a total solar eclipse. At the same location, at some time on June 29, 2024, the sun will be directly overhead. Where in the world is this?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something important, this seems to be a basic astronomy textbook problem instead of an astronomy puzzle, so I've voted to close it as [off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/are-math-textbook-style-problems-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing (with help from www.suncalc.org and www.eclipsechasers.com) that you might be on [Isla Socorro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socorro_Island) (a small island about 400 km south of the Baja peninsula). Or you could be on a boat (or swimming) a few km off-shore off-that island.

There appears to be a Naval base there, but I can't find a nice restaurant where you could sit and enjoy a beer while watching the eclipse.